# Need suggestion for creating a small JSON structure for a Ajax driven webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using PHP/jQuery/MySQL to build a small hotel website for my friend. Like a typical CRUD app it will have forms and reports. I have a PHP framework in place to render forms and save them using Ajax. Now I need to update the elements on webpage when a data item is saved. As this is a small project I would have gone with simple approach of sending HTML in Ajax response and embedding the response in webpage. But I decided to use JSON so that I can extend the framework to other projects. As of now following is my design idea:

```
{
  'status':'', /*status like success/fail */
  'message':'', /*a status message or sting will be more helpful in case of failure */
  'data':'', /*arbitrary data*/
  'datatype':'' /*is it JSON or HTML or javascript( or some thing else?)*/
}
```

Based on response jQuery will update/manage webpage elements. Am I missing some thing here or am I totally wrong in this design.

Answer (score 2):

I would not have status in there and would instead look at using the HTTP status codes to report back status. In PHP you can use `header()` to pass back a 400 if you get and issue. If you then pass back 200 if everything is OK.

Then in jQuery you can do:

```
$.getJSON( 'http://someUrl/action.php' ).success( function() {
  alert( 'success' );
} ).error( function() {
  alert( 'fail' );
} );
```

For you JSON structure I would then keep everything else you have.

```
{
  'message': '', /*a status message or sting will be more helpful in case of failure */
  'datatype': '', /*is it JSON or HTML or javascript( or some thing else?)*/
  'data': {} /*arbitrary data*/
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: The intention of status field is more for the server side operations such as db interaction etc. For example an operation may fail and I would need to notify this to user.

Comment: If you still need a message even when the status is not OK, then stick with your original design. My suggestion of HTTP status codes was due to that sometimes being used in REST and also to allow for the .success and .error use in jQuery.

Comment: I am not a jQuery ninja but know it does provide a way to look at headers and act accordingly, so I guess I can intercept 404/500 headers and act accordingly, in fact I am doing something similar to manage unauthorised ajax calls